# Internal transactions totaling 100+ Ether flowing into a wallet

Tags: contract-design, wallets, contract-invocation, etherscan

When you look at the wallet address below, it has a balance over 100 ETH but there are no inflows in the etherscan ledger to show where those funds came from

- https://etherscan.io/address/0x4adf0dbc8bb29a61be114c22879202a76790c9d9

Clicking on the etherscan tab called "Internal Transactions" instead, we finally do see the source of inflows, mostly coming from an Ethereum Contract, not another wallet.

- https://etherscan.io/address/0x4adf0dbc8bb29a61be114c22879202a76790c9d9#internaltx

Any guesses as to what in the hell type of a contract is paying out 40+ Ether at a time upon request, the type of contract interaction probably being invoked by the wallet holder, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any guesses as to what in the hell type of a contract is paying out 40+ Ether at a time upon request

A contract that is selling NFTs.

If you look at the top (internal) transaction in that list ([this](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x6ceaac315f47d1b603fc7e7f260eb15f3ca5b2836944202af2c9bd9fa0d67ed1) one), you'll see a series of transfers. If you look at the Input Data field, you'll see the called function:

```
Function: acceptBid(address _originContract, uint256 _tokenId) ***
```

So it looks like someone selling NFTs (on SuperRare, by the looks of it).

Without looking at the code I'd imagine there's some sort of escrow where bidders deposit ETH into the contract, which is released to the seller when the bid is accepted.